# ElasticSearch: Query post body not working but uri search working

Tags: elasticsearch

I am sending the following elastic-search query and it behaves perfectly well when sent via uri-search. But with post with body call - it doesn't work as expected. Kindly suggest how to correct the query.

This works:

GET CALL

```
<someUrl>/elasticsearch/index/_search?q=host:host-0
```

RESPONSE  (limited to host-0)

```
{
    "took": 4,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 128040,
        "max_score": 2.0973763,
        "hits": [{
                "_index": "123"
                "_type": "log_message",
                "_id": "123",
                "_score": 111,
                "_source": {
                    "host": "host-0",
                    "pid": 333,
                    "timestamp": "2017-04-06T04:29:44.724Z",
                    "priority": 7,
                    "namespace": "syslog",
                    "msg": "aaaaa"
                }
            },

            "_index": "345"
            "_type": "log_message",
            "_id": "345",
            "_score": 111,
            "_source": {
                "host": "host-0",
                "pid": 333,
                "timestamp": "2017-04-06T04:29:44.724Z",
                "priority": 7,
                "namespace": "syslog",
                "msg": "aaaaa"
            }
        }, 
        .....
}
```

This doesn't work:

POST CALL

```
<someUrl>/elasticsearch/index/_search
```

BODY for POST Call:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "host": "host-0" }
    }
}
```

RESPONSE (does not limit to host-0)

```
{
    "took": 4,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 128040,
        "max_score": 2.0973763,
        "hits": [{
                "_index": "123"
                "_type": "log_message",
                "_id": "123",
                "_score": 111,
                "_source": {
                    "host": "host-1",
                    "pid": 333,
                    "timestamp": "2017-04-06T04:29:44.724Z",
                    "priority": 7,
                    "namespace": "syslog",
                    "msg": "aaaaa"
                }
            },

            "_index": "345"
            "_type": "log_message",
            "_id": "345",
            "_score": 111,
            "_source": {
                "host": "host-0",
                "pid": 333,
                "priority": 7,
                "namespace": "syslog",
                "msg": "aaaaa"
            }
        }, 
            "_index": "546"
            "_type": "log_message",
            "_id": "546",
            "_score": 111,
            "_source": {
                "host": "host-0",
                "pid": 222,                 
                "priority": 7,
                "namespace": "syslog",
                "msg": "aaaaa"
            }
        }, 
        .....
}
```

The Get on this index returns
GET /elasticsearch/

```
      "host": {
        "type": "string", 
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
```

Comment: How do you send your queries? With which client?

Comment: also please share your schema mappings and version

Comment: I am new to elasticsearch - how can i retrieve the version and mapping?

Comment: version: `GET "http://elasticsearch-url:9200"`
mapping `GET "http://elasticsearch-url:9200/index/_mapping"`

Comment: @JoshiFriday69 `total hits` in both calls is same(128040). i.e both calls are returning same results. But as `host` field was `not_analyzed` you should get results which contain only `host-0` for both calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your GET call, the token `host-0` is analyzed. If you try the following GET call (by surrounding `host-0` with double quotes), you'll essentially get the same query as your POST call, and you won't get any results.

```
<someUrl>/elasticsearch/index/_search?q=host:"host-0"
```

If you want results, you need to use a `match` query instead of a `term` one. That will be equivalent to `...?q=host:host-0` in your GET call.

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : { "host": "host-0" }
    }
}
```

In the end I think that your `host` field has the `text` type while it should have the `keyword` type.

Comment: OP is saying that he was getting results for both GET and POST calls(which is looking weird for me in this case). if `host` field is analysed then we shouldn't get results for POST call unless he used some other analyzer!

Comment: This is what I get on getting the index 
"host": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },

Comment: This seems more of a postman tool problem - results from command line curl work correctly